# How to enter function variation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I put **var this** , into attr in the picture?
because that was replaced to be innerHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/jquery-lightbox/demo/js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button href="http://allcartooncharacters.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Tweety-310x310.png">Try it</button>

<p id="demo">
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/img_pulpitrock.jpg" alt="Pulpit Rock" width="284" height="213">
</p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('button').click(function() {
       var this = $("button")[0].getAttribute("href"); 
       $("#demo img").attr("src", '+ var this +');
   });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And what if I want to add the function of loading ? maybe if the image is successfully opened , the loading will disappear like this

```
if (loading) {
    $(".loading-picture-gif").show();
} 
else {
    $(".loading-picture-gif").hide();
}
```

Comment: Is it just me or is it hard to see what OP really wants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `this` as a variable name, and even if you could, it's probably not a good idea. I'd make your code look like the following

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var newSrc = $("button")[0].getAttribute("href");
    $("#demo img").attr("src", newSrc);
});
```

As for the hiding/showing of the loading image, you can use `.on("load"...` when you change the `src` attribute of the image as a callback. Final code looks like this

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var newSrc = $("button")[0].getAttribute("href");
    $(".loading-picture-gif").show();
    $("#demo img").on("load", function() {
      $(".loading-picture-gif").hide();
    }).attr("src", newSrc);
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/puqk1t15/1/)

Comment: what if i have 3 buttons . and when clicked, it appears the image of the button ? check pleas :D https://jsfiddle.net/aritabacan/0ufao000/

Comment: You should be able to modify the code to follow my example. Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/a42mxghx/2/

Comment: Please open https://jsfiddle.net/aritabacan/nxjj8vkv/ .... How I made $ (."SS1 " ) disappears when I click $("body") ? cause if I use code like this .    $("BODY").click(function() {$(".ss1").css('display', 'block'); });    .. I can not, because $(." SS1 ") located in the < body>

Comment: You should ask this in a new question

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a reserved keyword and you should not use it as a variable name, instead what you can do is

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('button').click(function() {
       var href = $(this).attr("href");
       $("#demo img").attr("src", href);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button href="http://allcartooncharacters.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Tweety-310x310.png">Try it</button>

<p id="demo">
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/img_pulpitrock.jpg" alt="Pulpit Rock" width="284" height="213">
</p>
```

Comment: what if i have 3 buttons . and when clicked, it appears the image of the button ? check pleas :D https://jsfiddle.net/aritabacan/0ufao000/